# Simple SQL Server table LINQ learning query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Preamble:

I'm trying to learn C#/LINQ by creating a new application from an existing program. Essentially, I'm porting SQL stored procedures to C#/LINQ code with a new database and slightly different functionality. Although I've had assistance with getting going I've ran into my first what some might say trivial problem.

Although any correct answer would be very much appreciated so would direction. (e.g. is it just a query with simply a Group Into clause? have I missed a similar question in stackoverflow? I have lots of learning tools at my disposal thanks to browsing stackoverflow for a number of months, [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), C# In Depth, C# 4.0 in a Nutshell and [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). The information is great, it's just that I'm a bit overwhelmed by it.

Question:

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
([Id] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [LineManagerId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Email] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [IsAdmin] [bit] NULL,
)
```

The primary key is `Id`, the `LineManagerId` is a foreign key of `Id`.

I would like to would like to write LINQ code to query the database to find if an `Id` is a `LineManagerId` AND if so select all the Ids that that `LineMangerId` has?

I've had an attempt as follows but am missing some what I reckon are very basic skills in my understanding of LINQ.

```
var ismanager = from manager in Users
                join man in Users on manager.Id equals man.LineManagerId
                select man.LineManagerId;
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Give this a shot:

   var ismanager = from Users user
   join on manager where manager.Id equals user.LineManagerId
   select user.LineManagerId;

Comment: I think the answer is that I've asked two questions in one and not understood my joins correctly. I have marked my question as answered below. I put some test values into the database as follows.INSERT INTO [User]
           ([Id]
           ,[Name]
           ,[LineManagerId]
           ,[Email]
           ,[IsAdmin])
     VALUES
           ('account\Alice'
           ,'Alice'
           ,'account\Bob'
           ,'alice@alice.com'
           ,1
           )

Comment: I do want to thank all responders. I have plenty to learn from here already. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to would like to write LINQ code to query the database to find if an Id is a LineManagerId AND if so select all the Ids that that LineMangerId has?

Taken literally that's two separate queries, but here's one that will give you all of the users under a line manager:

```
string managerID = "1";  // The manager ID to query
var userList = from manager in Users
   join u in Users on manager.Id equals u.LineManagerId
   where (manager.Id == managerID)
   select u.Id ;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to would like to write LINQ code to query the database to find if an Id is a LineManagerId AND if so select all the Ids that that LineMangerId has?

I'm not really sure, why do you need any joins here.

```
IQueryable<User> query = Users.Where(x => x.LineManagerId == id);
bool isManager = query.Any(); // first query to check if manager
if(isManager){
   IEnumerable<User> users = query.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray(); // second query to fetch Ids
}
```